# Can I turn a DP Cable into a HDMI Cable?

Tags: hdmi, cable, displayport

I have seen that you can buy adapters to put on the end to convert a DP cable into a HDMI.

Is it possible to put one on each end to effectively turn it into a HDMI cable?

Reason being that I accidently bought a DP cable thinking it was a HDMI cable and had it installed into the wall...

Any insight would be much appreciated

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can just use adapters in this case without issue.  DisplayPort actually uses exactly the same video signaling as HDMI (and DVI-D), so the adapters don't even need power as they're just changing the connectors.

Make sure you get good quality adapters though, cheap ones can cause noticeable issues with signal quality.

Comment: DP does not use the same signal as HDMI/DVI (i.e. TMDS). If the source port is actually an DP++, you can convert the port to a HDMI or DVI port and use a corresponding cable for that.

Comment: With that said, I'm not denying that it might also be possible to put passive adpater on both ends as the cable might be able to carry TMDS signal.